# Slow processing time of a list

Tags: python, list, for-loop, timeit

Why is my code so sluggish (inefficient)? I need to make two methods to record the time it takes to process a list of a given size. I have a `search_fast` and `search_slow` method. Even though there is a difference between those two search times. `Search_fast` is still pretty slow. I'd like to optimise the processing time so instead of getting `8.99038815498` with `search_fast` and `65.0739619732` with `search_slow`. It would only take a fraction of a second. What can I do? I'd be eternally grateful for some tips as coding is still pretty new to me. :)

```
from timeit import Timer


def fillList(l, n):
    l.extend(range(1, n + 1))
l = []
fillList(l, 100)

def search_fast(l):
    for item in l:
        if item == 10:
            return True
    return False

def search_slow(l):
    return_value = False
    for item in l:
        if item == 10: 
            return_value = True
    return return_value

t = Timer(lambda: search_fast(l))
print t.timeit()
t = Timer(lambda: search_slow(l))
print t.timeit()
```

Comment: If you mean that it takes a long time before you get the result: Timeit takes a long time as executes the function 1000000 times. https://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html

Answer (score 1):

The fastest way is using `in` operator, which tests membership of a value in a sequence.

```
if value in some_container:
    …
```

Reference: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#membership-test-operations

Update: also, if you frequently need to test the membership, consider using sets instead of lists.
Some pros and cons can be found here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset

Answer (score 1):

Adding the following code to above:

```
t = Timer(lambda: 10 in l)
print(t.timeit())
```

produces the following on my system:

```
0.6166538814701169
3.884095008084452
0.29087270299795875
>>>
```

Hope this helps. The basic idea is to tap into underlying C code and not make your own Python code.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find out what made the code sluggish. It was a simple mistake of adding to the list by`extend` instead of `append`.

```
def fillList(l, n):
    l.**append**(range(1, n + 1))
l = []
fillList(l, 100)
```

Now `search_slow`clocks in at `3.91826605797` instead of `65.0739619732`. But I have no idea why it changes the performance so much.